# Issue with MVC Routing?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue in Routing in MFA where link like

- `Project_Name\Controller\Index` is working, whereas
- `Project_Name\Controller\` is not working

This is happening for only some controllers after being deployed in a server.

I am getting the following error:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Is there any further configuration values that needs to be considered?

Comment: The question is asking *why it is not working in some case*. It is hard to say without having access of the machine. Please modify the question with some code

Comment: The default action name is configured as routing defaults. Are you sure these controllers that return 403 have this particular action? What defaults (if any) you have in your routing config?

Comment: Default route is not defined in your route initialization

Answer (score 0):

In RouteConfig we define the route path like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

So the controller you are using may have Index action method and the URL works.
But if your controller does not contain Index method or it is having parameters then it will not work.

This is a possible solution that you might create an action method named Index in all those controllers.
for more, you need to share some more details.

Comment: Actually I had already made the default route as defined above. The actual problem was that I have defined 'Windows authentication - true'  in my server configuration file which did not allow me to access the files. I removed that and it started working properly for me.